# How do I reply on my own topic?

Tags: support, questions, reply

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stackoverflow: Should I answer my own question, or not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/stackoverflow-should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not)

How could I add a reply on my own question?
Like in the most other forums?

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/stackoverflow-should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not (plus others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply by adding a reply, just like you would for any other question. It doesn't work any differently if you asked the original question.

However, SO is not a forum: it's a question and answer site. Unless you are actually providing a real answer, you should probably edit your question instead. See

- [Should I not answer my own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/stackoverflow-should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not)
- [Etiquette for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)

Answer (score 2):

StackOverflow is not a forum.

Edit Your Question to Add More Information, or simply add a comment to your own question.

If you have an **answer** to your question, you can go to the bottom of the page and click on the "Answer Your Question" (or something to that regard) button, and you will be able to post an answer to your question.

And while you are at it, read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)