# Etiquette: How do I insert some useful info into the form of a question

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette, hyperlinks

For example, I have found the link to a PDF with VS keyboard shortcuts very useful. But being constrained by the question/answer format, it seems a little clunky to ask the question "where can I find a PDF with VS keyboard shortcuts?" and then answering my question. Is there any convention (or should there be) for just injecting quick and useful links and such? And is that kind of thing appropriate for SO? I'm assuming the answers "no" and "yes" in that order but would like to hear from others.

Comment: Duplicate of [Etiquette for answering your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)?

Answer (score 2):

In this instance, you could search for "visual studio keyboard shortcuts" and discover that it has been [both asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750177/visual-studio-2010-keyboard-shortcuts).

In the general case, yes, it is appropriate. I would recommend generalizing your question as much as possible, though; instead of asking where to find a PDF, you might ask for a list. Which is what the linked question did.

Comment: I see what he did there. His non-question question was not in the form of a question. Cool that my example is a fine example of what I was asking.