# What is the best way to answer your own question?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Etiquette for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)

What if you figure out the answer to your own question, what is the approved way of answering your own question?

Comment: this should be asked on meta.stackoveflow.com

Comment: (@Xtian: "StackOverFlow" has one space too few, and an erroneous capital F!)

Answer (score 2):

The best way I would say is **to** answer your question when you're sure you have the right answer.

If the community does think your answer was correct/useful for your question you get the [Self Leaner Badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/14/self-learner).

Answer (score 0):

Just wait a few days... I'm not sure of the precise amount of time, but in a few days you'll be able to select your own answer as THE answer.

Comment: You have to wait at least 2 days to accept your own answer to a question, but you don't have to wait that long to *post* the answer.

Comment: I received an error saying that I could not even "post" my answer until 24 hours have passed and suggested that I edit the original question instead.  I don't mind waiting before selecting the correct answer but why the mandatory waiting period before I can "post" an answer?