# Can I publish my own solutions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, open-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Posting and answering questions you have already found the answer to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to)
>   [Should I ask a question I know the answer to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to)
>   [Etiquette for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)

I know Stack Overflow is there for asking questions. But what if I just had a problem and developed my own solution and want to share it with the world? Is it ok to fake a question to achieve this, and if not, where on this planet can I publish open source code in a nice-looking way similar to Stack Overflow?

Comment: See [is it ok to ask and answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)