# Ended up solving my own problem/question - what to do with the post?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Etiquette for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)

i have asked a [question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985960/prevent-element-from-wrapping-around-floating-sibling-element) about an alternative way to avoid using `overflow:hidden` and prevent shadows from clipping. technically it's another "clearFix" question.

several versions came up, researched further and still not a viable alternative approach. the day after, i ended up using the same approach but improved it the way i wanted it to do.

should i:

- vote to delete?
- vote to close?
- answer my own question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's kosher to answer your own questions. Mark it as accepted so as to prevent it from getting bumped

Comment: Yep the [faq] even says "*It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).*"