# Why was my question downvoted although I was just sharing my knowledge, Q&A-style?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, etiquette

We can share knowledge by answering our own questions.

[image]

Reading [this Stack Exchange blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) helped me understand that

- if you have a question that you already know the answer to
- if you’d like to document it in public so others (including yourself) can find it later
- it is OK to ask, and answer, your own question on a relevant Stack Exchange site.

I have gone through [Etiquette for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question). But it talks about answering your question a while after you've posted it – not immediately.

How can we teach people there is option for sharing knowledge also?

I have [tried to use this functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411417/what-is-the-difference-between-unlink-and-unset-in-php) and got a lot down-voted a lot. When I told others about this "feature", some people reverted their down votes.

Comment: I would have downvoted/closed your question too, had I seen it.  When you post a question for the sole purpose of answering it yourself immediately, it looks like you're trying to use SO as your personal blog, and that's not what it's for.  The question wasn't posted in good faith, given that the point of SO is for people to get solutions to *actual* problems they are having.

Comment: Your question was *bad*. You're asking "What's the difference between these two completely unrelated functions that share absolutely nothing in common except the first two letters of their name?". You might as well ask "What is the difference between an apple and an airplane?" This question isn't useful to anybody in any way, and posting such a bad question looks like an attempt to game the system and gain rep.

Comment: The community should keep their "high level", and you should adapt, not otherwise. I've been also in the place of asking a "bad" question and got a few downvotes but it's fine. The community is actually helping you to make better questions in a crude manner, but often effective.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> I have tried to use this functionality and get a lot down-voted a lot. When I said about this feature then I some people reverted their down-votes.

The thing is: Those questions you ask and answer yourself, they should be **actual good questions** that would be accepted by the community even if you didn't already have an answer for them.

The MSO topic [Etiquette for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) doesn't mention this, of course. It's from 2009 – please don't take it as the ultimate reference. Also, it was talking about answers posted much later, which implies that your question had to "survive" until then, so to say (i.e. not be closed, deleted).

Also, Jeff's blog post clearly links to his own question on Super User: [Disable Java Plugin in Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/201613/disable-java-plugin-in-google-chrome) – now look at your question. Do you see a difference? Here's your question:

> What is difference between unlink and unset in php?

Oh, wait. That's it? Let's assume you hadn't posted your answer below. Would this be considered a good, on-topic question for Stack Overflow, showing research effort? I guess not. Only seein the question, there's context missing: Where's your code? What's your actual problem with these two keywords? Why did you confuse them and in what situation did that occur to you?

This is why it's downvoted. It's simply a terribly bad question, sorry.

---

Of course, we're trying to share knowledge. But knowledge on a Q&A site means: in the sense of providing solutions to actual problems. Creating wiki-like answers or replacements for simple PHP documentation with a set up question is encouraging others to flood the site with equally bad questions – even though they don't have an answer yet.

If you feel like you always have to point others to Jeff's blog post that explains answering your own questions in fear of being downvoted otherwise, then there's something wrong with your question and you should probably fix it.