# What happens if i answer my own question?

Tags: support, answers

I am thinking about answering my own question but i still would like to be able to mark an answer from someone else as the solution. Currently the FAQ has no information what happens if a user answers his own question. This [question is about the etiquette which](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question?rq=1) is not quite the same.

Could you add this to the faq?

Comment: Why would it change anything to answer your own question? You can still accept any answer you want: your own, someone else's, or none.

Comment: I was unsure about the fact if it would change anything. In the link i added is a comment that some people do not like the fact, that someone answers his own question.

Comment: There should be no one who frowns on self-answering. If there is, they are quite simply *wrong*. Point them [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), or [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking), or [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you answer your own question, you can still accept any other answer.

You can also accept your own answer, but you must wait 48 hours after the *question* was posted to accept *your own answer* to it. (Source: [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide))

Comment: Thanks - so it has no side effects. 
The only possible downside could be that people frown upon the self answer.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree Right. Self-answering has no bearing on your ability to accept, vote on, edit, or do any action that you may or may not otherwise be able to do relating to any other answer. Btw, answering your own question is not actually looked down upon (as you can see from votes on answers to that question). [It's encouraged.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) If your answer expresses the same thing as another answer, you generally shouldn't post it, but that's the same whether what you're answering is your own or someone else's.