# Answer is deleted, Answer and question is down rated, Not able to understand Moderator policy

Tags: support, specific-question, down-votes, deleted-answers

I did few hard and extensive search on few point of facebook graph API exploration.
My question matched with few PHP geeks' question, I answered there and got negative votes.

I got java community matching with Facebook Error Code:1, I am not able to answer there(require 10+).
I found the above error question is raised after two days of extensive search on stackoverflow and facebook-developer community by that time I solved it by self and came back to Stackoverflow.

I made a separate question and in message field I answered that(Might be wrong way and till now closed)-Accepted.

Got bad comment but till now I am not clear what wrong happened.

Request for help from moderator

Comment: Is this a rant, a question, a... something else?  Links to your specific questions/answers would be helpful.  A clear question here would be helpful as well.

Comment: The question in question is [probably this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740150/for-native-desktop-app-send-notification-facebook-error-messagean-unknown-erro)

Comment: @HugoDozois - yup, you're probably right.  I can see why that was closed;  I still don't understand what `answer is deleted` is referring to, I don't see a deleted answer in the question.

Comment: I think he was trying to find a question that fit his answer. He got downvoted the first time, and faced new user restrictions the second time. Eventually he started a new question and answered it (in the question body), and got closed.

Comment: Thank you Andrew Barber, I know that Geeks are polite too. But till now I got my solution by self and completed my Research/Project work and handed over my research to production division. Its functioning well. I am looking forward to learn spring/Spring MVC and want to explore FB-open SDK in Java. I have already worked with facebook-google API.

Comment: Dear Antony, first I tried to find only answer but didn't get. I solved it by self. after 1 and 1/2 day I tried to post my solution but not allowed even in comment in matched question. Now I have learned how to use and for what to use stackoverflow. Thanx to all :)

Comment: SF isn't SO, they have their own scopes and site cultures - useful to know if you end up there. I think the current answer covers most of what you need to do. I'd add, when self answering, make sure you do it jeopardy style (IE, the question needs to look like a question), and tick on the self answering checkbox. If you find the answer later, don't forget to give credit to any answer that helped.

Comment: Dear Journeyman Geek I am not able to see self answering checkbox help by screen-shot

Comment: @Blah Blah Grabblesnackers, question was a rant-accepted because I doesn't get help rather a re-think comment from adeneo. What exactly wrong happened is only cleared by Hugo Dozois

Answer (score 17):

I've looked at your question, and actually it's because you didn't follow the policy about answering your own question. It's correct to answer your own question, but **don't** do it within the question body. Post a question **then** post the  answer of the question separately. You can do that whether by using the special checkbox for self-answering at the question creation *or* by posting an answer separately.

That way people looking at the question will be able to understand what the question is. The way you posted it isn't clear.

See [etiquette about answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question).

Comment: There's even an option when you ask a question (a small tickbox) to post an answer along with the question immediately. =)

Comment: A very thanx Hugo Dozois and J. Steen, I think I am not good at presence of mind. Thank you.

Comment: @pkm1986 you should edit your question that is closed (to make it look like a question). Then manage to get it reopened. When it is reopened, post your answer to the question.